# How to create cronjob for stopping the application in every month different date

Tags: cron

I need to create a cronjob for stopping an application every month at different date. For example: time: 2 am, date: jan 5th, feb 7th, mar 15th

```
00 02 * * * /export/home/jira-8.5.3-install/bin/stop-jira.sh
```